# Embedded RavenDB Logging in debug output

Tags: vb.net, ravendb

I am currently investigating in RavenDB and set up this simple test

```vb
<TestFixtureSetUp()>
Public Sub Setup()
    _embeddableDocumentStore = New EmbeddableDocumentStore With {.DataDirectory = "localdatabase"}
    _embeddableDocumentStore.Initialize()

End Sub

<Test> Public Sub CreateDB()
    Dim session = _embeddableDocumentStore.OpenSession()
    Dim results = session.Query(Of testclass)().ToList()

    For Each testclass In results
        session.Delete(testclass)
    Next
    session.SaveChanges()

    session.Store(New testclass With {.Id = 4, .Name = "177mdffarsdfdffds6t2in611"})
    session.Store(New testclass With {.Id = 2, .Name = "17fd7martrsdfdffds6t2in611"})
    session.Store(New testclass With {.Id = 3, .Name = "re177marsdfdfffdfds6t2in611"})
    session.SaveChanges()

    results = session.Query(Of testclass)().ToList()

    For Each testclass In results
        session.Delete(testclass)
    Next
    session.SaveChanges()        
    results = session.Query(Of testclass)().ToList()

    Assert.AreEqual(0, results.Count())
End Sub

<TestFixtureTearDown()>
Public Sub TearDown()
    _embeddableDocumentStore.Dispose()
    _embeddableDocumentStore = Nothing
End Sub
```

But can I get the embedded RavenDB database to write debugging info to the visual studio Debug Output? I have tried adding a nlog.config in the bin\debug folder with this content, but when I debug I get no info about queries in the output... What am I doing wrong?

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.netfx35.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Console" Name="Console" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="Raven.Client.*" writeTo="Console"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Forgive my poor VB translation, I usually develop in C#*

Specifically regarding logging in unit tests - I find it much easier to use the abstraction layer and forget about NLog.

```vb
Imports Raven.Abstractions.Logging

...

<TestFixtureSetUp>
Public Sub Setup()
    LogManager.RegisterTarget(Of DebugTarget)()
End Sub

Class DebugTarget
    Inherits Target

    Public Overrides Sub Write(logEvent As LogEventInfo)

        ' whatever you want to do
        If logEvent.Level >= LogLevel.Info Then

            Debug.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", _
                            logEvent.TimeStamp.ToLocalTime().ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"), _
                            logEvent.Level, _
                            logEvent.FormattedMessage)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

In regards to your test as a whole - there are a lot of problems:

1. Unit tests should not write to disk.  Not only is there a performance cost, but multiple tests could step on each other.  Run in memory instead.
2. Don't use test setup/teardown for the document store.  Each test should get its own in-memory document store.  Put it in a `Using` statement block to dispose on test completion.
3. Don't try to manage your own cleanup by deleting records.  Just start clean each time.
4. Sessions should **always** go in a `Using` statement block. Whether testing or in real code.
5. When testing, it's good practice to create separate sessions for the Arrange/Act portion of your test and the Assert portion.  Otherwise, you aren't necessarily checking what's in the database - you might just be checking what's tracked in the session.
6. Unit tests should always use the `WaitForNonStaleResults` customization on any queries.  Otherwise you may be testing stale results.  [Read here for more information about stale results.](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/stale-indexes)

[Here is a complete example of your test written properly.](https://gist.github.com/4540196)

Comment: thanks a lot! I usually start writing some tests when experimenting with new stuff, so it's not always a clean unit test by definition, that explains the mess. And it took me an hour to find out WaitForNonStaleResults